# How do we get public IP history

Tags: ip

I got my public ip by [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com), but it changed every modem restart. Any hope to get a list of public ip as history.

Kindest Regards,

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways I can think of to achieve this:

1. Router Logs
2. External DNS Service
3. Custom Tool

**Router Logs**

This is highly dependent on the model of your router and what it stores. Consult your router's documentation for more specific instructions.

**External DNS Service**

This would be the easiest to do. On your router you would configure a dynamic DNS service such as [No-IP](http://www.noip.com), [DynDNS](http://dyn.com), etc.
I am not sure about DynDNS, but for No-IP, they have 90 days of IP address history for their ["Plus Managed DNS"](http://www.noip.com/managed-dns) paid plan.

**Custom Tool**

If you are tight on budget, you could write a script that pulls the results of www.whatismyip.com or a similar service every time you turn your PC on or on a regular schedule.

The simplest address to pull would be to download [`http://checkip.dyndns.org`](http://checkip.dyndns.org) which is a page with "Current IP Address: 155.143.XXX.XXX" as it's content. Download the file, check if the last one is different, if different, save to a CSV file. There are various grievances to this, but it's free and could be done with a simple script.

If [`http://checkip.dyndns.org`](http://checkip.dyndns.org) is too simple, you can also use [`https://ifconfig.co`](https://ifconfig.co)